# Calling/reloading a smarty template with ajax within another template

Tags: ajax, templates, smarty

I have a div in my smarty template, into which I want to call a PHP file via ajax which will fetch/display another template file. This will contain a list of pages on a site which will be ordered, and you can click up/down arrows to reorder them so I need it to reload the same template after each click.

Is this possible?

```
<div id="pagelist_container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  {literal}
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#pagelist_container").load("path_to_file/pages.php");
    });
  {/literal}
</script>
```

Then the pages.php would be:

```
$smarty->display('ajax/pages.tpl');
```

Whenever I put the smarty line in I get a 500 error.

Comment: Can you write the error?

Answer (score 0):

You **must** create a new smarty object in your ajax response file, notice that you will have to include `Smarty.class.php` in this file. This is the contents of the `path_to_file/pages.php`:

```
// include smarty (assuming you have smarty in your path)
require_once('Smarty.class.php');
// initialize smarty
$smarty = new Smarty();
// setup cache, template_c & templates directory
$smarty->templates_c = "templates_c";
// assign any variables to smarty here
$smarty->assign('<variable>', $variable);
// fetch output for your pages
$output = $smarty->fetch('ajax/pages.tpl');
// return the content of the template to ajax caller
echo $output;
```